# Can I break on Errors in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, crash

[Errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) are not the same as Exceptions and now my Android app keeps crashing with an Error during debugging from Android Studio without breaking (the app just quits).

My question is thus, is it possible to make Android Studio break on Errors and not just Exceptions so that I may figure out what is causing this horrible bug?

If not, what is the best way to debug this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the fatal errors with the try/catch and the Exception class. In my case when my app crashes for application errors if I have try/catch I can see the lane and capture the error and repair it,basically I never found error that try/catch can't capture it. I think you need start narrow your code, part by part, finally you locate the code when your app crashes. Not existing a magic formula for find a fatal error, just need a time and revise your code.